# How to access a variable that inherits to a php class that we called?

Tags: php, class

we have two class A & B:

```
class A{
var $settings;
function getinfo(){
    $settings['domain']="mydomain";
    $settings['pass']="1234";
    return $settings;
}
}

class B extends A{
$ads = A::getinfo();
function makeurl(){
    return "template/".$ads['domain'];
}
}
```

now i have an instance of B in my page, but i need "pass" , maybe some code like this:

```
$theme=new B();
$mypass = $theme->A->getinfo;
echo $mypass[$pass];
```

I know this code is full of faults , but i could not write a better one. is there any solution to access to password without making an instance of A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is as simple as this:

```
$theme = new B();
$mypass = $theme->getinfo();
echo $mypass['pass'];
```

You can also improve your classes a bit:

```
class A
{
    var $settings;
    function getinfo()
    {
        $this->settings['domain'] = "mydomain";
        $this->settings['pass'] = "1234";
        return $this->settings;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    function makeurl()
    {
        $this->getinfo();
        return 'template/' . $this->settings['domain'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not call the settings variable in A from the B instance since B is a subclass of A?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're pretty close:

```
$theme=new B();
$settings = $theme->getinfo();
$mypass = $settings['pass'];
echo $mypass;
```

Answer (score 1):

if B extends A, all protected and public members of A are inherited into B, so you can access them directly.

```
class A {
  protected $foo;

  public function __construct() { $this->foo = 1; }
}

class B extends A {
  public function bar() {
    echo $this->foo;
  }
}


$b = B();
$b->bar();
```

Comment: yeah, I'm writing mostly python these days, this one slipped :) thanks

Comment: NP. :) I think OP needs a good tutorial to learn the basics... visibility/scope is for the lesson 2, IMO

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<?php
class A
{
    var $settings;

    function getinfo()
    {
        $settings['domain'] = "mydomain";
        $settings['pass'] = "1234";
        return $settings;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    function makeurl()
    {
        $ads = $this->getinfo();
        return "template/" . $ads['domain'];
    }
}

$theme=new B();
$mypass = $theme->getinfo();
echo $mypass['pass'];
```

Answer (score 1):

What about making settings a public static variable in A?  By making it a class variable you won't need an instance of A.

```
class A {
    public static $settings;
    // getter and setter methods here
}

// code elsewhere
echo A::$settings['pass'];
```

Also because your class B extends A it inherits the methods and properties, so you could call

```
$theme = new B();
$mySettings = $theme->GetInfo();
```

Comment: OP seems to be learning the basics. This should go in lesson 2... IMO